# How to run this particular command when an user login?

Tags: shell-script, sudo

Every time i login i have to run this 2 commands:

To be able to make caps2esc program work. But i want to automate this process

```
cd ~/Apps/caps2esc
sudo bash -c 'nice -n -20 ./caps2esc >caps2esc.log 2>caps2esc.err &'
```

I have tried the following with no success:

Add a bash script so that it can use sudo without the password i guess:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/user/Apps/BashScripts/caps2escAuto.sh
```

casp2escAuto.sh (i already made it executable):

```
cd /home/user/Apps/caps2esc ||
sudo bash -c "$(nice -n -20 ./caps2esc>caps2esc.log 2>caps2esc.err &)"
# Also tried without 'sudo'
# bash -c "$(nice -n -20 ./caps2esc>caps2esc.log 2>caps2esc.err &)"
```

I know that if I want the file to be run when i start X i need to add it to `.xinitrc`.

But what about running the script right after the user logged?

Comment: What OS are you using? if it's a recent Linux with udev and systemd you might want to look at configuring it to run as a udevmon service instead. See for example [How do I install caps2esc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979359/how-do-i-install-caps2esc)

Comment: You can only run `sudo /home/user/Apps/BashScripts/caps2escAuto.sh`. That's this line in `sudoers` allows. You cannot run `sudo` **inside** the script, just run the script with `sudo`.

Comment: You also shouldn't run your `nice` command inside `$(...)`. That's command substitution (google or search in `bash` manual if you don't know what this is). Just run the `nice` command as is, without `sudo bash -c "$(...)"`.

Comment: Also `||` will run the second command only if the first command failed. In your case, if your `cd` succeeded, it won't run the next command. Replace it with `&&`.

Comment: Thanks @aviro I fixed my script with your suggestions and the program it's working correctly.